# Changing date strings with jQuery and Regexp

Tags: jquery, regex, date, replace

What kind of code should I use so that jQuery looks for every YYYY-MM-DD formatted (plain text) string on a page and it replaces it with DD-MM-YYYY?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd strongly suggest encompassing the dates with a recognisable element, rather than trusting (any) JavaScript to reliably parse and convert plain-text strings meaningfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might work:

```
$(document.body).contents().each(function(i,e) {
    $(e).text(function(i,text) {
        return text.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g, function($full, $year, $month, $day) {
            return [$day, $month, $year].join('-');
        });
    });
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Jm2UQ/